# How should I update the version of Rustup? not updating the version of rustc or cargo

Tags: rust, rustup

I am pretty new to Rust and currently reading Rust book on the official website.

I am now looking into Rustup, which I think is very cool.

I get that we can manage the version of rustc and cargo with Rustup, but what if I want to upgrade Rustup's version in the future? How can I do this?

Comment: `rustup help`...

Answer (score 26):

From the [guide](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/basics.html), `rustup` will check for updates to itself (in addition to the toolchain updates) every time you run `rustup update`. You could also exclusively update rustup by running `rustup self update`.